# PHP function exec() stop loading site

Tags: php, laravel, exec

I'm making a dashboard to start programs on my computer in VueJS and I used the following code to start this program:

```
    public function start() {

    if(session()->get('serverRunning') !== 'running') {
        session()->put('serverRunning', 'running');
        exec('cmd.exe /c start C:\Users\jensm\websites\MinecraftServer\public\server\run.bat');
        return (['message' => 'Running']);
    } else {
        exec('cmd.exe /c stop C:\Users\jensm\websites\MinecraftServer\public\server\run.bat');
        return (['message' => 'Offline']);
    }
}
```

But after that my website keeps loading and won't return anything. Only if I close the command prompt program from windows, then it will give me the message. But I want to keep the command prompt open.

Comment: You checked if the server you are running on (Eg Apache) has access to run cmd.exe? If not grant it :) , i had this issue when trying to run python files so i feel the pain

Comment: I have acces, the cmd.exe is running with the code but then my website keeps loading untill I close the cmd.exe but I don't want to close it

Comment: Not sure why your running a `.bat` file by running CMD. Why not just directly run and skip the process of opening cmd? `system("cmd /c C:[path to file]");`

Comment: That does nothing, the bat file is not running

Comment: Nvm it is running now I used a backslash instead of the normal slash

Comment: Can you also close the program with system?

Comment: Updated the answer for this.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with windows scripting but are you sure that the thing you run with `exec` is terminating? If not code execution will be stuck at `exec` waiting for it to complete

Comment: Yea I get a new window so it's running, but the process only stops when I close the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments,

You were running `exec` which launches a command prompt, and from there you were then running a further process to execute a `bat` file.

The solution to this is to simply use `system("cmd /c C:[path to file]");` . This essentially runs the bat file through `system` without having to open a command prompt.

Have a look at the documentation for [System](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php). You do not need stop the program execution (As per to your further question in the comment)

Comment: That works, but then the php process is still running this must be stopped, but idk how.

Comment: That's something to do with your bat file then which is a different question. Just read the docs which i already provided you.